# What is wrong with my ajax ? its just doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, timeout

I don't know what is the problem a simple ajax request refuse to run normal, i test it on different hosting same issue. any ideas ?

**o.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ksearch(){
var dataString = $("#areax").val();
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "csv.php",
           data: {html: dataString},
           success: function(data)
           {
        $("#update_div").html(data);
           }
         }); // end ajax
}// end function
</script>
<textarea id="areax"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="ksearch();" >Submit</button>
<div id="update_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**csv.php**

```
<?php
$str = $_POST['html'];
sleep(40);
echo $str;
?>
```

All firebug details posted with pictures here
http://pho.to/4BLeG

**Edit 1**

the script run just fine from any connection, some clients only withh slow connection suffer from this problem.

**Edit 2**

the success call back return empty response  after 30 sec mark, although max execution time and set time limit set to no limit in php.ini with safe mode off and even php sleep() dosen't counted in execution time ... with sleep below 30 sec the script run fine on slow connections

**Edit 3**

link for phpinfo

```
http://69.50.252.196/php.php
```

@Damiano Barbati it doesnt work,
@Deryck it doesnt work
thanks for the help anyway

Comment: SO what is the problem? What does it means - refuse to run normal? Also why you use `sleep`?

Comment: sleep simulate the php function which take 40 sec

Comment: What do the http server error log files say? Waht does the browser console say? No sense to _guess_ what might be wrong.

Comment: It can be browser timeout, not server one.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Then fire within a shell:

```
curl -d "first=1&second=2" "http://69.50.252.196/csv.php"
```

What's the output?

Edit:

I get the following:

```
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/0.7.65</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is not related to the php_time_limit but with the php-fpm time limit, follow some guide like this one to fix it.

http://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/increase-script-execution-time/

Answer (score 0):

First, both of these (Firefox 25 and Chrome 31, respectively) work on consecutive attempts:

[image: Firefox 25]
[image: Chrome 31]

This isn't a surprise, I'm sure.  Where you start seeing errors is when you mix another connection with your `sleep()` function (that for some reason goes for 40 seconds).  `sleep()` is going to tie up that process completely until it receives an interrupt signal or completes its time.  This means if one person is trying to attempt the same thing before that 40 seconds completes, they won't get anything back unless they send the request before the timer hits 20 seconds (deductive reasoning based on my browser getting the 504 timeout at 60 seconds).

Maybe you intended this, maybe not.  Either way, read below for a way to manipulate this to work better for you.  The following won't cut the wait time down any longer but it will result in a data response (which by the way, you should set to `dataType: "text"` in your `$.ajax()` function to save bandwidth and processing).  If you want to cut into the function and interrupt the `sleep()` (or simply allow another execution in the middle and continue running the sleep timer), you can use [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php#99445).

Without more details on your server setup (PHP, nginx specific settings) I can only point you to the [PHP `sleep()` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) and the [504 Gateway Timeout Tips for nginx](http://www.nginxtips.com/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/).

Essentially you'll want to use these settings in your config files:

**php.ini**

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

**/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf**  -  *(only if variable previously used and needs to be changed - otherwise it will take the value of max_exec_time above by default)*

```
request_terminate_timeout = 300
```

**nginx host config file**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

The main change for the last one is the `fastcgi_read_timeout=300;`

After typing this I also looked at @Damiano Barbati's response and the site he links to is basically the same information.  If you still have issues, place an `info.php` file that we can access (make sure no passwords, etc are in your php.ini file) and put this code in it:

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

Good luck!